# Vue-tables-2 grid component usage, how to use the Event bus?

Tags: events, vue.js, vue-tables-2

I am trying to discover this matfish2/vue-tables-2 component, basic usage is fine but trying to read among the holes in the documentation is tricky...  few examples on Google..

In the doc , it's stated :

**Events**

```
Using Custom Events (For child-parent communication):

<v-server-table :columns="columns" url="/getData" @loaded="onLoaded"></v-server-table>
Using the event bus:
Event.$on('vue-tables.loaded', function (data) {
    // Do something
});
```

So I tried it in my UsersPage.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="users" class="container">
    <div class='users'>
      <v-client-table :data='tableData' :columns='columns' :options='options' @loaded="onLoaded"></v-client-table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import { Event } from 'vue-tables-2'
export default {
  name: 'UsersPage',
  data () {
    return {
      columns: ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'birthday'],
      tableData: [ ... ],
      options: {
        perPage: 5,
        perPageValues: [ 5, 10, 15, 20 ]
      }
    }
  },
  ready: function () {
    Event.$on('vue-tables.loaded', (data) => {
      console.log('Loaded...')
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

But It's not working ... where am I wrong ? How to check these events ?
thanks for feedback

**UPDATE**

I ried to modify my UsersPage script as following, no errors, but also no console log ...

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Event } from 'vue-tables-2'
Vue.use(Event)
export default {
  name: 'UsersPage',
  data () {
    return {
      columns: ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'birthday'],
      tableData: [ ... ],
      options: {
        perPage: 5,
        perPageValues: [ 5, 10, 15, 20 ]
      }
    }
  },
  created () {
    Event.$on('vue-tables.loaded', function (data) {
      console.log('Loaded...')
      console.log('My event has been triggered', data)
    })
  },
  methods: {
    onLoaded ($event) {
      console.log('My event caught in global event bus', $event)
    }
   }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading the deprecated Vue-tables version .... I discover that this event is only fired w the server side ... not the client... 
The documentation is missing a lot of examples and quite difficult to understand for Vue.js new comers...

vue-tables.loaded (server-side)

Fires off after the response data has been attached to the table. Sends through the response.